# Change matrix figure layout

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, matrices

I have a figure where I am writing som matrices I want something like

[image]

but I am getting this, How to change it?

[image]

I have

```
\begin {figure}[h]
\centering 
\small
 \textbf{X}
\[\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
x_{11} & x_{12} &\cdots & x_{1d} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} &\cdots & x_{2d} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots  \\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} &\cdots & x_{nd} \end{array} \right)\]
\[ \boldsymbol{n \times d} \]
\textbf{Data}
\Huge 
\[\downarrow \]
\small
\textbf{\[\rho\]}
\[\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\rho_{11} & \rho_{12} &\cdots & \rho_{1d} \\
\rho_{21} & \rho_{22} &\cdots & \rho_{2d} \\
\vdots    & \vdots    &\ddots & \vdots    \\
\rho_{d1} & \rho_{d2} &\cdots & \rho_{dd} \end{array} \right)\]
\[ \boldsymbol{d \times d} \]
\textbf{Correlation Matrix}
\Huge 
\[\downarrow \]
\small
\textbf{U}
\[\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
u_{11} & \cdots & u_{1d} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
u_{d1} & \cdots & u_{dd} \end{array} \right)\]
\[ \boldsymbol{d \times d} \]
\textbf{EigenVectors}
\textbf{\[\Sigma\]}
\[\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{11} & 0         & \cdots \\
0                & \ddots & \vdots    \\
\vdots        & \cdots & \sigma_{dd} \end{array} \right)\]
\[ \boldsymbol{d \times d} \]
\textbf{Singular Values}
\caption{ Steps in matrix notation of SVD}
\label{fig:stpeE}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I will update my answer below later to satisfy what you want with a more intuitive way of typsetting such complex diagrams. Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin {figure}[h]
 \[
 \begin{array}{ccc}
 &
 \textbf{X}
 &\\
 &
 \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
x_{11} & x_{12} &\cdots & x_{1d} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} &\cdots & x_{2d} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots  \\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} &\cdots & x_{nd} \end{array} \right)
&\\
&
\boldsymbol{n \times d}
&\\[2ex]
&
\textbf{Data}
&\\
&
\downarrow
&\\
&
\resizebox{12pt}{!}{$\rho$}
&\\
&
\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\rho_{11} & \rho_{12} &\cdots & \rho_{1d} \\
\rho_{21} & \rho_{22} &\cdots & \rho_{2d} \\
\vdots    & \vdots    &\ddots & \vdots    \\
\rho_{d1} & \rho_{d2} &\cdots & \rho_{dd} \end{array} \right)
&\\
&
\boldsymbol{d \times d}
&\\[2ex]
&
\textbf{Correlation Matrix}
&\\
&
\downarrow
&\\
\textbf{U} & \textbf{S} & \mathbf{V^T}\\
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
u_{11} & \cdots & u_{1d} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
u_{d1} & \cdots & u_{dd} \end{array} \right)
&
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
s_{11} & \cdots & s_{1d} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
s_{d1} & \cdots & s_{dd} \end{array} \right)
&
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
v_{11} & \cdots & v_{1d} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
v_{d1} & \cdots & v_{dd} \end{array} \right)
\\
\boldsymbol{d \times d}& \boldsymbol{d \times d}&\boldsymbol{d \times d}\\
\text{Eigen Values} & \text{Singular Values} & \text{Eigen Vectors}
 \end{array}
 \]
\caption{ Steps in matrix notation of SVD}
\label{fig:stpeE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use an `array` to create the diagram itself. You can play around with the vertical spaces by adding empty lines or `\\[<length>]`.

Comment: Cool answer, let me modify the last part
`\boldsymbol{d \times d}& \boldsymbol{d \times d} & \boldsymbol{d \times d}
 \end{array}
 \]`
instead of
`\boldsymbol{d \times d}& \boldsymbol{d \times d}7\boldsymbol{d \times d}
 \end{array}
 \]`

Comment: Excuse me, If I want to use \mathbf how can I accomplish it?

Comment: @cMinor What do you mean? You mean `\mathbf{<content>}` instead of `\boldsymbol`? There is also the alternative; that is, using the `bm` package and writing `\bm{<content>}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative answer:

To get the large arrow, I defined a new command.  Also, I create your matrices using the `pmatrix` environment.  It's worth looking this environment up.  By defining your own environment for matrices:

```
\newenvironment{mymatrix}{\begin{pmatrix}}{\end{pmatrix}}
```

You can very easily change the parentheses to braces or none or some other style.

To get the three matrices at the bottom, I nest within another `array` envrionment.  This will help with the labeling above and below each of the matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Hdownarrow}{\mbox{\Huge$\downarrow$}}
\newenvironment{mymatrix}{\begin{pmatrix}}{\end{pmatrix}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin {figure}[h]
\centering 
\small
\[
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \text{\textbf{X}}        \\
    \begin{mymatrix}
        x_{11} & x_{12} &\cdots & x_{1d} \\
        x_{21} & x_{22} &\cdots & x_{2d} \\
        \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots  \\
        x_{n1} & x_{n2} &\cdots & x_{nd} 
    \end{mymatrix} 
    \\[2ex]
    \boldsymbol{n \times d}  \\[4ex]
    \text{\textbf{Data}}     \\
    \Hdownarrow              \\
    \rho                     \\
    \begin{mymatrix}
        \rho_{11} & \rho_{12} &\cdots & \rho_{1d} \\
        \rho_{21} & \rho_{22} &\cdots & \rho_{2d} \\
        \vdots    & \vdots    &\ddots & \vdots    \\
        \rho_{d1} & \rho_{d2} &\cdots & \rho_{dd} 
    \end{mymatrix}
    \\
    \boldsymbol{d \times d}            \\
    \text{\textbf{Correlation Matrix}} \\[2ex]
    \Hdownarrow                        \\[3ex]
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        \text{\textbf{U}} & \text{\textbf{S}} & \text{\textbf{U}}\\
        \begin{mymatrix}
            u_{11} & \cdots & u_{1d}    \\
            \vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
            u_{d1} & \cdots & u_{dd} 
        \end{mymatrix} 
        &
        \begin{mymatrix}
            \sigma_{11} & 0      & \cdots    \\
            0           & \ddots & \vdots    \\
            \vdots      & \cdots & \sigma_{dd} 
        \end{mymatrix} 
        &
        \begin{mymatrix}
            \sigma_{11} & 0      & \cdots    \\
            0           & \ddots & \vdots    \\
            \vdots      & \cdots & \sigma_{dd} 
        \end{mymatrix} 
        \\
        d \times d & d\times d & d\times d   \\[2ex]
        \text{\textbf{EigenVectors}} & \text{\textbf{Singular Values}} & \text{?}
    \end{array}
\end{array}
\]
\caption{ Steps in matrix notation of SVD}
\label{fig:stpeE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, *never* use `eqnarray`. Here a simple `$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}` would do (and dispense with many `&`'s). Why `\providecommand` and `\renewcommand`? Wouldn't `\newcommand` suffice?

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't realize `eqnarray` was depricated.  `\newcommand` is sufficient.  The `providecommand` got in there because of a feature on my editor which I forgot to turn off. :(